# JQUERY SELECT AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

the following code works fine for me to show various sql-results after change a select-field:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#main_kat').change(getDropdownOptions);    
});

function getDropdownOptions() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $.post('/ajax/joe.php?qid=<? echo $row_job['sub_quali'];?>', { value : val}, populateDropdown, 'html');
    $("#send").prop('disabled', false);
}

function populateDropdown(data) {
    if (data != 'error') {
        $('#subcat').html(data);
    }
}
```

my problem: for a new insert everything is great because i have to select manualy, but if i use this code for my update form, i want to have opend my div #subcat allready.

i tried following at the beginning:

```
kat = $('#main_kat').val();
getDropdownOptions(kat);
```

kat is set (checked) via alert, but the function will not be fired... where is my mistake ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see any param for `getDropdownOptions()` function?! What are you looking for? Please improve your question. Post relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not just call the function because you are using it with this.

```
kat = $('#main_kat').val();
getDropdownOptions(kat);


function getDropdownOptions() {
      var val = $(this).val();
```

change to:

```
getDropdownOptions();


function getDropdownOptions() {
      var val = $(document.getElementById('main_kat')).val();
```

Comment: use `$("#main_kat")` instead of `$(document.getElementById('main_kat'))`

Comment: If you won't use jQuery, what's the use of using jQuery at all, you could just as well have var val=document.getElementById('main_kat').value; instead. ^^

Comment: you can use jQuery to other much more complicated things, or can combine performance (messing with the DOM) won with a time of development using jQuery.For example search for classes, attributes, among many other things it allows us

Comment: This kind of performance is so negligible. I think, in this case, the bottle neck might be in db performance, not in jQuery selectors.

Comment: insignificant, then work with a large mass of data between server and client and work with her on the page, each "inisgnificancia" brings a memorable effect

Comment: If you bring a massive amount of data to your page, then you have a problem with your front-end design. In this cases you can, and should, use ajax requests, pagination, ... Besides that, in jQuery I can select multiple elements (including multiples Ids) in a single statement, try to do that with getElementById.

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend you to replace your getDropdownOptions function by this:

```
function getDropdownOptions(val) {
  val = val || $('#main_kat').val();
  $.post('/ajax/joe.php?qid=<? echo $row_job['sub_quali'];?>', { value : val}, populateDropdown, 'html');
  $("#send").prop('disabled', false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will probably work fine if you ensure that the `this` reference points to the correct object when you call the function. Instead of passing `kat` as a parameter you could just call the `getDropdownOptions` method with the following code:

```
getDropdownOptions.apply(kat);
```